# Cardio/ Jujitsu excercise without using legs

Tags: injury, jujutsu

I have hurt my right foot,(painful to walk on) but I don't want to put on weight/ lose any cardio fitness/ lose my Jujitsu skills while I am resting up.

So what would the best exercises/ routines  I could do to keep my stamina up, along with my jujitsu skills.

Comment: It depends on what the "hurt" is. You're not going to lose much stamina/conditioning if you take it easy for a week or two. For the jujitsu skills, practice them in your head while you're resting up so you stay up to date mentally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endurance training in the martial arts can be divided into four different groups.

**1 - is a general endurance training**
For general endurance training it is best to resort to cardio-trainings such as running or swimming (but with a leg injury, it may be difficult).

**2 - is training the muscle groups that are rarely used**
In that case the choice of exercises depends on your personal characteristics and martial arts school. Ju-jutsu schools is characterized by basic movement techniques (kihon). So you can easily adjust exercises to your school kihon to training the most important muscles.

**3 - a practice proper breathing**
If you already have a sparrings experience, you should know that the greatest difficulty - is the control of breath. The most part of popular japanese martial arts is based on the same principles so is not going to be a problem if you will train any of existing methods to control breathing in a battle. That is good way to improve your skills especially if the injury prevents you to normal training

**4 - is training movements on the principle of minimal sufficiency**
The basic idea is avoidance of unnecessary movements. You should aim to be more effective instead of being too active.

Endurance training method is highly depends on the person, so i guess it should be a personal set of exercises